# Some questions about System.IO.File.Copy in C# and the copy, xcopy, robocopy commands

Tags: c#, file, copy, xcopy, robocopy

My C# Windows service application copies a lot of files over network via SMB, FTP or SSH all day and night. To do the file copies I simply use `System.IO.File.Copy`. Which command does the .NET Framework execute here? Is it *copy*? Maybe *xcopy*? Is this different on different Windows versions? I also read about *robocopy* but it seems there is no API. Is it worth the effort using P/Invoke with *xcopy* or *robocopy* instead of simple copy? At the moment I doubt that for my case.

In a future release I have to copy all files in two remote directories instead of one. So what happens when I copy a file via

> File.Copy("c:\test.txt", "\\server1\dir1\test.txt")

And then call

> File.Copy("\\server1\dir1\test.txt", "\\server1\dir2\test.txt")

Will the files be copied twice from my server to the target server? As far as I understand my computer says to copy files from A to B so the files will be transfered from A to my machine to B, am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To do the file copies I simply use System.IO.File.Copy. Which command does the .NET Framework execute here?

It uses the [CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) routine in the windows API.

> Will the files be copied twice from my server to the target server?

No, your example first copies from A to B and then from B to C. This is really inefficient because the second copy operation reads the file data back from B to A before it sends it to C. You should instead have two copy operations from "c:\test.txt" to two different destinations.

**edit**: I looked into it and it turns out that the file will not be read back to the local machine *if you are copying within the same remote shared folder*. So in your example where you are copying within the `dir1` share, there is no problem. But as soon as you copy from one share to another, this optimization is lost and the file will be read to local memory during a copy operation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response but can you give me more info about your second statement? Why is "A to B and A to C" more efficient than "A to B and B to C"? You say the file must be "read back from B to A", isn't this the same effort than an "A to C" copy? The connections are really slow to some servers so the best solution would be to copy the files only one time and then do a local copy on that server to another dir but I think this is not possible via builtin C# methods.

Comment: I've updated my answer, it turns that windows does optimize this under certain conditions. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71465/moving-remote-files-without-implicit-local-copying

Comment: Nice to know Windows optimizes some of those copy operations, thanks. I will go with "copy A to B" and then "copy A to C" like you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

File.Copy() pinvokes the CopyFile() winapi function.

The xcopy.exe and robocopy.exe programs are separate utilities.  They also use CopyFile(), their value-add is in handling more than one file at a time.  Which of course has many complications beyond copying a single file at a time, they have lots of options to use wildcards, iterate sub-directories and making the copy conditional.

None of them have a special option to make duplicate copies.  There is no point to it in general, just copy twice.  The second copy will be a *lot* faster as long as the file isn't too big, the source file data will be present in the file system cache so doesn't have to be read from the disk again.

Answer (score 2):

`XCopy` and `robocopy` are programs, and `copy` is command of windows' command line interpreter: `cmd.exe` (which is a program too).
.Net's `File.Copy` uses none of the above, and instead uses the win32api command `CopyFile` (as those programs probably do too).

So the answer of your question depends on the implementation of windows (which can change in future releases).
The documentation does not state if the file is copied locally, but its data is almost certainly transmitted locally, and then sent to the other server (no need to save it on the local disk).
[CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)